# Persistent Session with Python requests to scrape behind login

Tags: python, session, web-scraping, python-requests

I can login on the webpage i want to scrape but the next "get" request after the login "post" request is not behind the login.

the code is as follows so far (the webside is the one i want to scrape):

```
def main():

    # request session and get login url
    with requests.session() as s:
        login_url = "https://www.websitetoscrape.de/login"
        result = s.get(
            login_url,
            headers=dict(referer=login_url, useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0")
        )
    
        #  set authenticity token
        tree = html.fromstring(result.text)
        authenticity_token = list(set(tree.xpath("//input[@name='authenticity_token']/@value")))[0]
    
        # define payload for login
        payload = {
            "member[email]": "mail_here",
            "member[password]": "pw_here",
            "authenticity_token": authenticity_token
        }
    
        # post login
        result = s.post(
            login_url,
            data=payload,
            headers=dict(referer=login_url)
        )
    
        # get side behind login
        url = "https://https://www.websitetoscrape.de/other_side"
        result = s.get(
            url,
            headers=dict(referer=url)
        )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

looks like my login was wrong -.-'

Comment: That probably means login failed

Comment: ***"i want to scrape but the next "get" request after the login "post" "*** - The  `get`  request comes **before** the `post`

Comment: welp looks like my pw was wrong -.-'